# I have a little problem with a certain command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making a bot for myself to do stuff, and I tried to make a kill command

```
if (CMD_NAME == "kill") {
    let target = message.mentions.members.first()
    message.reply(`${target} is die`)
}
```

and I came to the conclusion that the bot doesn't know what is `message.mentions.members.first()` in general, how do I fix that? Also if I need to show more code, tell me

Edit: how I coded in the prefix:

````
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(PREFIX.length)
        .split (/\/s+/)```
````

Comment: Can you edit your post with error message?

Comment: there isn't any. I started up my bot and did ^kill (someone) (^ is the prefix) and nothing happened (no errors at all), however, when I just did ^kill, the bot replied with "undefined is kill".

Comment: then your `message.mentions.members.first()` is undefined, meaning you didnt get any members at all when you pinged.

Comment: very weird, the other mate (on DIscord) that gave me the code said it worked fine for him, should I put my code for detecting commands in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments under your question, I think your problem might be somewhere else.

```js
const PREFIX = "!"
let str = "!a b c"
const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = str.trim().substring(PREFIX.length).split(/\/s+/)
console.log(CMD_NAME)
console.log(args)
```

outputs:

```
a b c
[]
```

So it appears that your code is putting whole msg as "command name" which probably makes it fail name check and that's why nothing at all happens.
Changing that split regex to `/\s+/` to properly detect whitespaces changes the output to:

```
a
[ 'b', 'c' ]
```

which would probably fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck on that command for a good day or so, I appreciate you for your help